# Program doesn't stop iterating through list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def gameinfo():
    lines = []
    html_doc = 'STATIC.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_doc), 'html.parser')
    for mytable in soup.find_all('table'):
        for trs in mytable.find_all('tr'):
            tds = trs.find_all('td')
            row1 = [elem.text.strip() for elem in tds]
            row = str(row1)

            sausage = False
            with open("FIRE.txt", "r+") as file:
                for line in file:
                    if row+"\n" in line:
                        break

                else:
                     if row.split(",")[:4] == line.split(",")[:4]:
                        print(row)
                        print(line)
                        file.write(line.replace(line+"\n", row+"\n"))
                        print('Already exists with diff date')
                        sausage = True
                        break

                if sausage == False:
                    print(row.split(",")[:4])
                    print(line.split(",")[:4])
                    print(row)
                    print(line)
                    file.write(row+"\n") 
                    print('appended')

    while True:
        gameinfo()

gameinfo()
```

This program is supposed to keep searching the text file `FIRE.txt` for lines that match the variable `row`. When i run it, it works okay, but the part of the code that is supposed to check if the first four elements of the list are the same, and then skin the appending section below, doesn't work. When the program detects that the first 4 elements of a string turned into a list(row) that matches with another string's first 4 elements that's in the text file, it should overwrite the string in the text file. However when it detects a list that has the same first 4 elements, it loops forever and never breaks out.

My string looks like this: 
['Infield Upper Deck Reserved 529', '$17.29', '4', '2', '175']
and i compare it to a list that looks like this:
['Infield Upper Deck Reserved 529', '$17.29', '4', '2', '170']
and when it sees that the first 4 elements in the list are the same, it should overwrite the one that was in the text file to begin with, but it is looping.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation?

Comment: Sorry, thought I fixed it before it was pasted.

Comment: Remove the `+'\n'`. File iteration strips newlines

Comment: Everywhere? When it outputs the data to my text file everything is in one line instead of rows when I do it like that. Would that not break the file read, as it read line by line?

Comment: Your row is already a list. Splitting it again will give you an attribute error. Please run the actual snippet you posted.

Comment: Yeah, my fault again, just added it, `row` is a string.

Comment: File iteration splits on newlines the items in the for loop will not have a newline at the end.

Comment: @equallyhero Can you read my answer please? It sidesteps this whole issue, if your data is a CSV like I think it is.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think you should see my updated code, I turn the list into a string, write it to the text file, then when I am reading it, turn it into a list, so I can compare the list in the text file and the new list that both match their first 4 elements.

Comment: That is... not a great way of doing it. If you're just using `FIRE.txt` with Python, might I suggest using `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`? It's much easier because it Just Works(TM). You could put in an OrderedDict where the key is a tuple of the first four items, and then you would only need a tiny, tiny loop.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yeah the program is temporary, I dont really need persistence and I won't be using this program more than a few times and a text file is just fine for storming what I need for now, will certainly use the lib in the future though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `for line in file` keeps newlines. Maybe you're thinking of `str.splitlines()`?

Comment: @equallyhero I've added a little thing to my answer that might help you; it's a function that simplifies the persistence of a single mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

Question has changed; most recent version last.

---

Methinks you want to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. If you iterate through a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object instead of the file object directly, you'll get each line as a a list.

Example:

```
import csv

row = ["this", "is", "an", "example"]
with open("FIRE.txt", "r+") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        if row in line:
            break
        pass
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need to use this in anything other than Python, you could `pickle` a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with a tuple of the first four items as the keys:

```
import collections
import pickle
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def mutable_pickle(path, default=object):
    try:
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
    except IOError, EOFError:
        obj = default()

    try:
        yield obj
    finally:
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(obj, f)

with mutable_pickle("fire.bin",
                    default=collections.OrderedDict) as d:
    for row in rows:
        d[tuple(row[:4])] = row
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, it does. The OP has a flawed assumption as to how part of Python works, and this part of Python works in the way the OP thinks that part of Python works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The OP was trying to see if a list was in a line. The only way that makes sense is if the line represents a list. CSV is the most common format where I've seen that.

Comment: If you see what the OP is trying now, it matches up with my answer perfectly.